# JavaScript for Searching an Element's Specific Ancestor Like in XPath?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

**Searching downwards** from a given node works wonderfully and crossbrowser-compatible with Javascript functions `querySelectorAll()` and `querySelector()`.

This functions allow to state any CSS3 selector for searching child elements. As far as I have understood, there is no way to search *parental* nodes: [W3 CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#selectors)

I'd like to search parent nodes too like possible with XPath axe *ancestor*. 
Something like (XPath):

```
select="./ancestor::*[@attributex='xxx'][2]"
```

Note that I haven't tried out the above XPath expression, and I'm not sure if it only selects the **nearest** ancestor, but that was my intention.

I know that I could [directly use XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript), but I'd rather avoid it as I don't know about 1) browser compatibility and 2) searching downwards works fine with `querySelector/All()`.

I'd also rather avoid some for-loop searching one `.parentNode` after the other and compare its `.getAttribute("attributex")` with the searched one.

Any ideas how to accomplish this with cross-browser-compatible JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would appreciate jQuery's parents([selector]) method. For sure it take advantages in terms of compatibility. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at jQuery, the parents() and closest() methods look promising. Though, I'd like to not use exernal libraries for my current project (but I wanted to take a look at jQuery for quite some time). Looks like I stick with a for-loop for now.

Comment: Ok, I also don't know about anyway to do this 'crossbrowserly' unless you create a recursive function that get parents() and compare if its ids match with what you expect. I think that jQuery is perfect for that, not least because you can use only its core api to do that, without the need to use any fancy plugin or have to study about how jQuery works.